# Typescript: How to get all possible return values from a type containing generics

Tags: typescript

I need to export all the possible return types from a function. For example,

```
interface Action<T, P> {
  type: T;
  payload: P;
}

export type Actions =
  | Action<typeof CHANGE_STATE, ChangeStateReturn["payload"]>
  | Action<typeof SET_PROGRESS_ERROR, SetProgressErrorReturn["payload"]>
  | Action<typeof SNACKBAR_OPEN, SnackbarOpenReturn["payload"]>;

export interface Reducer {
  (state: State, action: Actions): State;
}

const reducer: Reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_STATE:
      return Object.assign<{}, State, State>({}, state, {
        ...state,
        [action.payload.stateName]: {
          ...state[action.payload.stateName],
          [action.payload.key]: action.payload.value
        }
      });

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default reducer;
```

The reason for this is because I need the exported `Actions` as part of my state context:

```
interface CreateCtx {
  (): readonly [
    Context<{
      state: State;
      dispatch: Dispatch<Actions>;
    }>,
    Provider
  ];
}

interface Provider {
  (props: PropsWithChildren<{}>): JSX.Element;
}

export const createCtx: CreateCtx = () => {
  const defaultDispatch: Dispatch<Actions> = () => initialState;
  const ctx = createContext({
    state: initialState,
    dispatch: defaultDispatch
  });
  const Provider: Provider = props => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    return <ctx.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }} {...props} />;
  };
  return [ctx, Provider];
};

export const [Store, StateProvider] = createCtx();
```

And here's an example of the `changeState()` function:

```
export interface ChangeState<
  S extends keyof State = keyof State,
  K extends keyof State[S] = keyof State[S]
> {
  (stateName: S, key: K, value: State[S][K]): ChangeStateReturn<S, K>;
}

export interface ChangeStateReturn<
  S extends keyof State,
  K extends keyof State[S]
> {
  type: typeof CHANGE_STATE;
  payload: {
    stateName: S;
    key: K;
    value: State[S][K];
  };
}
export const changeState: ChangeState = (stateName, key, value) => {
  return {
    type: CHANGE_STATE,
    payload: {
      stateName,
      key,
      value
    }
  };
};
```

I'm having a major issue with this. Firstly, the payload value for `key` and `value` is always equal to `never`.

Secondly, I need to somehow return all possible return value types (from `Actions`) as part of my state context, however since generics are used in the `changeState()` function it means that I somehow to return every possible combination that could occur (e.g. for each possible combination of S and K).

I'm so incredibly stuck with this. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** [Here's a link to a demonstration that should explain this better](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/PTAEC5K6dv4VAUCUBJAdgSwC5YIYA2oAzjvjgKYpiJ30ORJJYZUBOAZvgMaWgBlclVABvJKFCcA9uwC2AeQyVwYiZKnTpqsu1YBzANzqAvsckz5AFQDu2tRo0AjfO1UYArnKeV250CZIgTzSGGSgrLgEhEIUKoLC-AC8DprySvHijjL2AEQ5uaYANOqWcrb2Wc6uqgDMxUHGNBCMrW1MqACCPHihoDgAngAOlCTN7RMMzJQAHkOyOKAhYYsAwgASnQByAOIAogD6AladVnugKbkb2-tHJ2e5TaiTLwjNAKpDACZxpImgADciB5RuNXuDoMxWBxuHxQKsABb4DD6SixKgAHnUAlAsyoGC+JFAAGtKANpJwEr8UqTyZT0ZQSpIANK4mb4wkkskUqlUADaAgAuhcuXTeZQBYKkAA+VIACjIcS2+Dk8QERVFqmZGqBhBBqgZkr5zMFAEpVIjkaiGQAlSg4DzsDAY9WgZnS4yBJCzebsRbQ3yw-iWlFoxJ2h1OrGSHF4ygEom0nkMkVJ+mJJlutkcxPc9NxSWpvPiyUy1KDEaqCuUHnXXaHY6nPb+Ib4AaEaT4L6qKqSRVUZWqg3+SS0rUjwHAtWJI0m-xmILTOYLJahcI8JGhhkWzfW-4pBWJQeM0U6qemi6yqrse2OjCpSTVi2bet3JuZySt9ud7sPjT9yhjw-DRaWAyRdRBdRJECaDPSeWgIUQ5o7S+Dw+HYMZnkQiEoTYQNeH4bpemdKwNQABSvdQn1AKwWzbDsu1UMjPWYVArARLAiU4-oEX4LA5F9cg2FAVs-QAOlAGhmjQUBlEoL4eO4nBpDZQTQCIYgcF4kTpBIEgsCcQhCJ6LBQgxUjQAo-phlGMTmj2MT9AkyxQAAAyI0znWrWsX1uRszg1MSgulVyNVwWTKHkollNAG9I3vDSdL0gyjMnPVQVQFyXVlZEFIxd0InvLT+FckM9ziCM71cwqYQIuy2O0m98BIPoXK07ieGRUAfFISL71YHj+CcaQcGUuRepMvobF4m83K+TjWxwDdqurZpuMoABHDwiH6FTXIAEQWigNwxDy1xCiS0EWOTORi5ZyAGxL5mSwz+Diu80pBTCwE4dhpHGxKzpI8jpSk1A0H0DBZH4YrcXYP72FAGxcARQQ9isA4yJtBQdhtPYBAEA49htbGbVAABaCIcAAciJG85GkAF5KkP7xvaolZhVIYjPq4BvWXP1rJGUAgaJJJ1AAHxFyavJsnybgbe49g1Mqwwq28nT5XIvwYr5ckFUHJCloGMW8+l0cx7HcfxwnidJjUBHtMi-v0G89L2eHZEqzXtfon99dB-m1IDLgCNAFC0N8eUAINDN1Jl1RRfNcUWKQZZwhvVD0NUCP0JFQ84g1XhiIvJJKL7ZGltRuVi88sTqwvXtQFQVW-l+CDQUcTqSGDXzFabcAoI0d6nVABQnAAK0oHoxOa-TIYxUQTAduOGWlOUl41ACNSbxwgrE7eh8cPla9CMSdZ-A+jxVShBR7I-HFAfeAJPmXz79rsr6VG-BTAx-X+Iu-b8n9aR33joAi+n8O4P2gg-EwpoJyoAUMVRG3dRigH0CpGaJ4SBoVRs1JYzV+ACAtljBQAApPYqwMZ2wUDaOyjhUBbBGoVHgeovjMwGuzNkXNUoEKhosG8RkgRsCHhw7gHhCA4EHo-WKGt7wAXnI0IOK5xH4EkYI+Skc-CsQQthV4zRVhNREABVceF2TqQJCJP6AIsAcPYGCfRLxdHoEhtDOGCMSASXYqMfgrh+CoRhipWG1YiQ+AMBEASCxmZ2mLkLdBWkKDoGaJ1DA1N-QYDYR4DhhVFJ00oEMP6WdiK4VqnCIxlA4irBwDMeUycmpfFCIQAYoA+RD1WKEKg7JF4PxjinB+80SCLQ3KoQ6QzjoIlOjLEgHoh4mGlMBZ2jM7G+HUIKVOIcgyWRsSsxGVQ5SFOkEMEgTE-rHIAOoo0RFgQgXwbzOiXtKZO5CBAAA0xJ7CMqqNgqcfQrnTosHgxjKDVJmBaYFoL86l3LmY8IaiNFjOGQiUZR0q5TOIjMqFl5CpRCIAyfwAKlg1JFECypVAOnmJwBvIefTIh4DxRmMRqKRmgHhVIxFEzTAIPUISpZtj7GnOWfYkUhzjnYqboSvk29WXMoRMKFIHge6518HKTO2iwrYHpTERI3LHAj3vBiHoMwxJ8t2Z9SgSRRCiDblQDUgykUBBMGIfeoqSBOuALM2C6h9WtKNeRHZ9j1nKJUYLSVQhoYrziKawNJKIU1LlNypAQA)

Comment: Would like to help, but your code as posted has to many missing parts. Please post a self contained sample demonstrating the issue. Also it is unclear to me what you mean by "export all the possible return types from a function" what is the desired outcome ? What type would you expect to extract and from which function ? `reducer` ? That has a return type of `State` as far as I can tell. Until you make the question more clear I (and I think everyone else) will not be able to help.

Comment: OK sure, it's hard to explain but I've created a demonstration with comments that should explain what I'm trying to do. Link in my original post.

Comment: You will have much better luck if your example code is [minimal and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Instead of including code with errors and telling us to ignore some of them, remove anything we should ignore.  If you can't include a type, remove the question's dependency on it entirely if possible, or if not, replace the missing type with a toy version.  It will be effort well spent.

Comment: I added a reproduction. Please see the edit in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it...

So the issue was that `Action<typeof CHANGE_STATE, ChangeStateReturn["payload"]>` wasn't working correctly as the default value for `<S>` is an enum (all possible `keyof State` values).

To fix it, I needed to add an `Action` for each possible value of `<S>` to the `<Actions>` type.

For example,

```
export type Actions =
  | Action<typeof CHANGE_STATE, ChangeStateReturn<"formOne">["payload"]>
  | Action<typeof CHANGE_STATE, ChangeStateReturn<"formTwo">["payload"]>
  | Action<typeof CHANGE_STATE, ChangeStateReturn<"foo">["payload"]>
  | Action<typeof CHANGE_STATE, ChangeStateReturn<"bar">["payload"]>
  | Action<typeof SET_PROGRESS_ERROR, SetProgressErrorReturn["payload"]>
  | Action<typeof SNACKBAR_OPEN, SnackbarOpenReturn["payload"]>;
```